# Hibernate statistic different at runtime as on test

Tags: spring, jdbc, mockmvc, hibernate-statistics

At runtime i'am sending get-request to my api and i can see, that hibernate executes 4 jdbc statements. One statement is a sql-join and second one is select-count for page-element and two other statements "hibernate fetch.subselects", which are for persistence-bag.

When I'am sending with MockMVC under WebapplicationContext get-request to my api to test, that it will be everytime 4 jdbc statements and not more, I am getting only two first jdbc-statements which I've described.

So how can I get during test-time the same amount of jdbc's like on runtime?
Controller:

```
@GetMapping({"/"})
    public String links(@PageableDefault Pageable page,
                         Model model) {
        Page<MyEntity> entity = service.fetchAllEntities(page);
        List<Integer> totalPages = Arrays.asList(1,2)   
        model.addAttribute("entity",entity);
        model.addAttribute("numbers",totalPages);   
        return "object/object_list";
    }
```

Test-Controller

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@Transactional
public class AllControllersTransactionTest {
    
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private Statistics hibernateStatistic;
    Session hibernateSession;
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                                        .build();
        entityManager = BeanUtil.getBeanFromContext(EntityManager.class);
        hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        hibernateStatistic = hibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        hibernateStatistic.clear();

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnAllLinksWith5JDBCStatmentsAsAutheticated() throws Exception {

        
        List<Integer> pages = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1,2});
        MvcResult result =  this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        LOGGER.info("QUERIES: ", hibernateStatistic.getQueries());
        assertEquals("SHOULD EXECUTED ONLY 4 JDBC STATMENTS", 4, hibernateStatistic.getQueryExecutionCount()); //At test-time, they are only two statments
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've switched off open-session-in-view in spring:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

Next point is, that i'am mapping my model into dto-object in my service-bean:

```
public Page<UserDTO> fetchAllLinksWithUsersCommentsVotes(Pageable pageable){
        Page<Link> ln = linkRepository.findAll(pageable);
        UserDTO.getMapDto(ln.getContent().get(0)); //additional two queries will be execued
        UserDTO.getMapDto(ln.getContent().get(1)); //no queries will be executed
        UserDTO.getMapDto(ln.getContent().get(2)); //no queries will be executed
        ArrayList<UserDTO> users = ..//get users;
        return new PageImpl<>(users, pageable, ln.getTotalElements());
    }
```

When i'am executing

> UserDTO.getMapDto(ln.getContent().get(0));

so i can see at runtime and during testtime,
that last two queries (persistence-bag with lazy-loading) will be executed.
Difference between runtime and testtime is, that during runtime hibernate shows 4 JDBC-Statments and on testtime only 2 JDBC-Statments by same-entries in the log (4 select-statments) .
So, why i can see 4 JDBC-Statments within log and runtime and testtime but i have different result within hibernate statistic on runtime and testtime.

Comment: This is probably because in your real application you are rendering a view, which needs a collection which is lazy loaded. Due to open-session-in-view the queries will execute during page rendering. This part isn't happening in your test, so 2 queries less. Also looks like you are testing the wrong thing (the result is what is important not the number of queries imho).

Comment: You are absolutely right, two last queries come during a page rendering. But i'am using here MockMVC with WebApplicationContext. So during the test i see in my log a webpage as html-text, so i thought, that these two last queries should be loaded too.
McvResult does not matter here, because i don't look a the moment for content, rather on hibernate-statistics. 
So how can i trigger t execute these last two statements during a test?

Comment: You cannot as there is no page rendering going on it will return the `ModelAndView` but not actually render the view. So no that isn't possible and as stated imho you are testing the wrong thing (you should be testing if everything you need is in the model not the number of queries you fire).

Comment: pls. look on update

Comment: There is no mapping in the controller code you posted and want to test, so not sure how those 2 lines are related.

Comment: i've posted just a code-lines, which do it. I've edited and described behavior

Comment: Still I don't get why it is so important that the number of queries match, if you change the entity your test(s) will fail. These tests are brittle, test the input and output. Also small tip the `Page` method has a `map` method if you want to change the type, a lot easier then what you do now and works regardless of the page size.

Comment: Cause when you model jpa-entities a wrong way, you get the same result with much more queries / effort. This test has a focus, that my model needs for instance 5 queries to get wished result and not 15 queries. How else would you test, that your model has no n+1 problem or something like that.

Comment: Actually you already have the N+1 problem due to the additional queries for the lazy loaded associations. Also the fact that you have 4 queries is probably due to your mapping (only mapping 3 elements not all the elements) and that in your test you have less data. There are tools like [Hypersistence Optimizer[(https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/) which will test things like this and more and you might want to check [this] for a better way of testing.